# Can't find active f-curve panel

Tags: animation, modifiers, interface, fcurves

I just started Blender 2 months ago and i'm having a great time.

I'm trying to add a noise f-curve modifier to my camera movement to create shakiness for a toaster animation kind of thing.

However when I add the noise it affects the whole duration of my animation when I only want it to be active for a certain period of time. From doing research it is my understanding that I should be able to have f-curve "parameters" show up in the n-panel on the right side of my viewport. From looking at videos of pre-2.8 blender the parameters show up but I can't find them anywhere.

So my question is : How to find this panel / How to restrict the noise f-curve modifier in Blender 2.8 ?

Thanks in advance. [image]

Answer (score 3):

Press button <kbd>N</kbd>  while hovering your mouse over the *graph editor* or click (or drag) this little left-direction arrow here:

[image]

Comment: Like shown in the screenshot I linked the N Pannel is active but there's nothing regarding f-curve settings in there unless there's something i'm missing

Comment: Oh ok found it, had to activate the panel in the keyframe window. Thanks !

Comment: Don't crop screenshots too much. A larger screen shot with the important part highlighted is easier to find, when you don't know the software enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Note the "Show Errors" icon in the upper right corner]
I also discovered this little icon in the Graph Editor panel, the one with the exclamation mark inside a triangle (upper right corner in the image).  It's the "Show Errors" only option.  If it's selected then you will not see any of your disabled or error-free F-Curves.  Surprise!